# jQuery UI Datepicker - date values don't pass through properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I've searched around for a solution for my UI problem - here and on other blogs and didn't come up with a solution yet.

I have an HTML file, with jquery UI datepicker in it,

**dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',

altFormat: 'mm/dd/yy'**

- are two options that are set in the datepicker. Basically, i want to show user European standard date, but pass on American standard upon submit.

When form is submitted, the script that interprets it sees the day as a month, month as a day and stalls.

How do i basically display Euro standards date, but process the American standards?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm a noob in JS, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Whats the code you are using. You can always get a timestamp and then display it however you want.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're setting a proper `altField` selector for an existing field.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/kyfEy/

Comment: +1 - And you could make the "actualDate" hidden if you wanted to, so you could submit in one format but display in the other. Nice.